# How to disable cross button of the screen in Install4j

Tags: user-interface, install4j

How can I disable cross button of screen.I want to disable top right corner cross button from installer screen please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 8.0, this is not possible. Custom window decorations are planned for a future release.